# How to correctly export from blender to opengl with a texture?

Tags: materials, export, opengl

I am learning opengl from [here](http://learnopengl.com/#!Model-Loading/Model) and we are given an obj file for blender of [crysis nanosuit](http://learnopengl.com/data/models/nanosuit.rar).

When I load this with opengl, it just loads fine. But then I imported the file to blender and added some color and made an ironman-suit on it. The picture looks like this [image: ironsuit]

Then I exported the file as .obj format and loaded it in opengl the same way as before.
But this time when I load the image, it just shows a black body with no color or anything. Just plain black. Why isn't any color showing?

Comment: How did you add the color to the mesh? How do you import the model into OpenGl and how do you render it?

Comment: I opened the blend file , I imported the model and added color through material , then imported the model through assimp and here is how I rendered it , http://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=mesh&type=header

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question about Blender. It is either about  whatever importer you are using, the ASSIMP library or OpenGL itself. OBJ is mainly a geometry based format, not really suited for material export.